# Забыли пароль на ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Есть веб-приложение бэкендом на ASP.NET Core. Надо добавить туда возможность восстановить пароль.

Нужен какой-то компонент, который может создать одноразовый временный код восстановления пароля для определенного пользователя, а потом проверить, был ли этот код создан для этого пользователя. Есть такой готовый класс?

Если нет, то как такое реализовать? Конкретно непонятно, как сделать коды действительно временными, т.е. чтобы они уничтожались через заданное время, а не хранились пока программа выполняется.

Сейчас в моем приложении пользователи создаются так:

```
await this.Repository.RegisterContact(login, password, role, name, email, phone, post, partnerId);
```

Проверка пароля при авторизации делается так:

```
var contactData = await this.Repository.AuthorizeWithPartner(login, password);
```

У класса, к которому относится `this.Repository` есть методы:

```
public async ValueTask<bool> RegisterContact(
    string login,
    string password,
    int role,
    string name,
    string email,
    string phone,
    string position,
    int partnerId)
{
    login = login.ToLower().Trim();

    if (this.contacts.Any(x => x.Login.ToLower() == login))
    {
        return false;
    }

    var contact = new Contact
    {
        Login = login,
        Password = MyHelper.GetMd5(password),
        Role = role,
        Name = name,
        Email = email,
        Phone = phone,
        Position = position,
        PartnerId = partnerId
    };

    this.AddContact(contact);

    return true;
}

public async ValueTask<AuthContactData> AuthorizeWithPartner(string login, string password)
{
    login = login.ToLower();
    password = MyHelper.GetMd5(password);

    var result = this.Contacts.Where(x =>
                         x.Login.ToLower() == login
                         && x.Password == password)
                     .Select(x => new AuthContactData
                                  {
                                      Contact = x,
                                      PartnerName = x.Partner.Name
                                  })
                     .FirstOrDefault();

    return result;
}
```

где `Contact` - класс, обозначающий пользователя, а

```
public class AuthContactData
{
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
    public string PartnerName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Под asp.net core тааак много всего написано, даже самими майкнософтами уйма статей было сделано по разным механихмам, не уж то поискать лень? Например вот, [первая ссылка гугла](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/16.6.php), а вот [документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, я нагуглил про UserManager, но он делает много чего, и у меня в программе он не используется, а создание пользователей и проверка паролей сделаны вручную. Поэтому хотелось бы какой-то компонент, который занимается только кодами восстановления пароля, но не созданием/изменением пользователей в базе.

Comment: Простите, а как сторонний компонент будет заниматься восстановлением паролей, где логика регистрации не стандартная, а написанная вами? Взялись за написание всего сами, так делайте и восстановление тогда тоже, сами. У Microsoft весь исходный код открыт, копируйте, разбирайтесь. Самое простое, что вы можете сделать - записать в базу уникальный токен и дату его создания, создаете страничку, которая принимает токен и проверяет его дату, все, вот вам простейшее восстановление. А готовое, ну уж извиняйте, я не думаю, что вы найдете такое, ибо вы грубо говоря не следуете стандарту)

Comment: "Простите, а как сторонний компонент будет заниматься восстановлением паролей, где логика регистрации не стандартная, а написанная вами?" - вот я и не хочу, чтобы он занимался непосредственно восстановлением. Этим другой компонент будет заниматься.

Comment: "Самое простое, что вы можете сделать - записать в базу уникальный токен и дату его создания ... " - @EvgeniyZ, а зачем его записывать в базу, почему его нельзя в памяти держать?

Comment: Ну во первых, что будет с вашей памятью, если не дай бог сайту придется перезагрузиться? Человеку заново придется проходить всю процедуру восстановления? Во вторых, такие токены обычно даются на 24 часа и предположим, что у вас сайт с большой посещаемостью и половина из людей забыла пароль, что тогда, забиваем память ненужной информацией? Хотя тут смотря как вы храните данные в памяти, обычно, для такого используют `Redis` в котором можно задать срок хранения. Вообще, данный токен похож чем-то на JWT, можете на его основе создать то, что вам нужно.